# Настройка WiFi-роутера

Tags: сеть, lan, wifi, роутер

Есть WiFi-роутер. К нему модключаются клиенты, для доступа к интернету. Собственно вопрос: как настроить роутер, чтобы клиенты между собой были объединены локальной сеткой?

Answer (score 2):

Они и так в одной локальной сети! Не понятно что имеется ввиду?

Comment: Если вин 7 рабочие группы находятся в центр управления сетями там в низу есть ссылкиесли хрюша то в сво-х мой компьютер-> имя ком. -> рабочая группа на всех пк должно быть одинаково и латинскими буквами

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить, что по умолчанию для рабочей группы видны (отражаются в сетевом окружении) только ресурсы с анонимным или полным доступом, для того что бы видеть запароленный ресурс с точным указанием пользователя (или группы) - данные пользователь (или группа) должны присутствовать на машине с которой осуществляется доступ, а для M$ ещё необходимо включить так называемую "службу обозревателя сети". Если дело касаемо Linux сегмента или смешанных сегментов, то рекомендовал бы почитать про настройку серверов SMB (samba).

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем точно задан вопрос... (что за роутер?, каковы текущие настройки?) но попробую ответить )))

По идее WiFi-роутер ,при подключении к нему клиента, выдает с помощью DHCP : IP-адрес подключения (если он не назначен вручную) из обозначенного в настройках диапазона. т.е. по умолчанию все локальные клиенты уже находятся в одной локальной подсети.

И остается только корректно настроить рабочие группы, или что там у вас, для обращения по NetworkName - или же сразу можно обращаться по IP-адресам к контенту, если на машинах присутствуют открытые сетевые ресурсы.

Comment: "И остается только корректно настроить рабочие группы" - да, настроить нужно, потому что напрямую конекта нету . . Как это сделать ?

Comment: А между собой машины хотя бы пингуются?